# multi-threading vs. clustering

Tags: node.js, multithreading, database-design, architecture

I'm researching the difference between these two concepts and I'm not finding clear answers to the following scenario:

You spin up 4 node servers on separate ports on a computer. These servers are all handling one one request.

I think this would be multithreading in theory. One request is delegated to 4 different node servers for processing.

However, because node operates asynchronously and I haven't yet defined how these 4 servers would interact with each other (does the job from node 1 then go to the job at node 2?), I don't think this scenario would be possible without some kind of master node.

This leads me to my next question:

Can multithreading also be asynchronous? To me, there should be a reason why this isn't a common programming paradigm, but I haven't been able to verbalize an example that confirms it

Thanks a lot! I normally ask programming questions but I'm starting to study system design more

Answer (score 2):

Even though NodeJS is single-threaded, asynchronous operations are run in separate threads thanks to its [Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) architecture.

> I think this would be multithreading in theory. One request is delegated to 4 different node servers for processing

You can scale a Node application by creating a node process for each available core in the CPU and/or by deploying the process in multiple computer instances. However, it's important to note the distinctions between a multithread application and a Node cluster application (or multiprocess).

- processes are typically independent, while threads exist as subsets of a process
- processes carry considerably more state information than threads, whereas multiple
  threads within a process share process state as well as memory and other resources
- processes have separate address spaces, whereas threads share their address space
- processes interact only through system-provided inter-process communication mechanisms
  context switching between threads in the same process is typically faster than context switching between processes.

> Can multithreading also be asynchronous?

Yes, asynchronous programming gives you the ability to stop and resume tasks before completion, on the other hand, multi-thread systems allow tasks to be run in parallel. Therefore you could have a system that run, stop and resume tasks between different threads.